# Removing additional double quotes in django rest response

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I'm new to Django rest framework, I tried to create a view

```
class TestView(APIView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return Response("Hello world")
```

When I send a request with curl or request module in python like this:

```
curl -X GET localhost:8000/test/
```

I get "Hello world" as a response, what I actually need is Hello world string without the additional double-quotes.
I tried different content_types, but none of them worked so far.
How can I get rid of the double-quotes?

Comment: Return a Django `HttpResponse` instead of a rest_framework `Response`. The rest_framework `Response` will convert the string into JSON which adds the quotes

Comment: @IainShelvington Is there any way to change that behavior?

Comment: @Maryam you probably should use custom renderer. Take a look at https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/

Answer (score 4):

As Iain says, use `HttpResponse` instead of `Response`

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

class TestView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponse("Hello world")
```